# Android ListView checked items base on id instead of position

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Android `ListView` show elements as checked base on element position. So if I add new element to the top, while some elements are checked, or remove element from the middle, wrong elements are shown as checked.

I have access to checked items ids list.

Is it possible to update `ListView` to show only checked items as checked? On which event I should do this (which method should I override)?

Comment: SHow us your code pls

Comment: In your getView inside your adapter put a condition that take your ids and do what you want in consequences.

Comment: You can set a boolean to the object to know if it's checked or not

Comment: @Tsunaze there is a problem with last element: I can't see effects of the last action in adapter getView. Details in comment under Armaans' answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in old Android version. I wasn't able to fix it there. In newer Androids it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this::

for this purpose you can use custom adapter for listview and in listview adapter there is GetView() method that can be used to achieve that you want.

Here is the Link for more info and [Example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: It works except one thing: on `getView` I have state from one action before. For example: when I checked first item, all items are marked as not checked. When I checked second item, first is marked as checked, second not. When I unchecked second item, both first and second are marked as checked.

Comment: Its may be problem in your check condition. I need to see your code for it.